# Confused about "notificationMode" and "clusterName" parameters in GridDB Installation

Tags: installation, griddb

I recently watched a video tutorial on GridDB installation, and the presenter highlighted the use of certain parameters in the configuration file, specifically `"notificationMode": "FIXED_LIST"` and `"clusterName": "myCluster"`. However, the explanation for these parameters was not provided.

I'm currently utilizing a WSL machine, and my GridDB version is "5.1.0-39692 CE.”

My question is:

Can someone please explain the significance of the `"notificationMode"` parameter in GridDB installation? What does setting it to `"FIXED_LIST"` imply?

Similarly, what is the purpose of the `"clusterName"` parameter? How does it affect the behavior of GridDB?

Are there any specific use cases or scenarios where adjusting these parameters becomes crucial?

I appreciate any clarification or guidance on these configuration parameters. Thank you!